# Get full URL of external website by JS, PHP or VBA

Tags: javascript, php, excel, vba, url

I am wondering is there a way to return full URL (or just params) of the website using JavaScript or PHP, or even VBA in Excel?

I can not preview this site in an iframe, because it gives me an error:

> ("frame-ancestors 'self'". error, Content Security Policy)

so I can't use window.location (probably because the Cross-Origin), I wonder how it can be done in the PHP or Excel VBA (how to use xmlhttp.Open in such case?), or with JS without returning the content itself. I don't need the content, but just the full URL or parameters, by knowing only a part of the URL.

I have the full list of ID's from the shop, so if it would be possible I could save a lot of typing for the reseller, because he uses ID in ordering specific stuff from his supplier. If I use the ID the website loads the content and changes the URL to a proper one - it looks like this (in the browser):

> My request: https://exampledomain.com/product_id=11
>
> After loading URL is: https://exampledomain.com/product_id=11&category=bikes&type=street

so the part I am interested in is **&category=bikes&type=street**, but also a full URL will be enough for further analyzing.

**TO BE MORE PRECISE, here are working examples:
observe how the URL changes after the content is loaded, and I need to grab new, changed URL**

> https://www.olx.pl/oferta/CID767-IDCkB7E.html
>
> https://www.google.pl/maps/place/Paris,+France/
>
> https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=Warszawa

Comment: I get 404 page not found with both urls.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what it is you're actually trying to do...

Comment: Seems like OP provided a clumsy example URL not being aware of domain grabbing. The string `&category=bikes&type=street`is part of the HTTP-Get parameter list (separated by`&`) of URL and can be accessed in various ways. Just search for e.g.`access HTTP-Get parameter `.

Comment: OP - We need to be able to reproduce your problem so please provide enough accurate detail to allow us to do so.

Comment: ComputerVersteher can you show the example how to get those parameters? But not by $_GET, as it works only on server side scripts, I need to catch this data by the external server

Comment: I take it you can't share the url for the actual site?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after.

```
'Import Everything From a Web Page:

Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://your_link_here/" ' should work for any URL
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

            x = .document.body.innertext
            x = Replace(x, Chr(10), Chr(13))
            x = Split(x, Chr(13))
            Range("A1").Resize(UBound(x)) = Application.Transpose(x)

            .Quit
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: something is loading to the worksheet, however page content is not what I need. I just need to return full URL when I send a request using only a part of the URL. Is there a way to do something like "on .ReadyDtate x = .document.url" ?